# copying structures from one table to other in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql, avro

I have got a avro table (table1) which has 5 fields and all of them are structures with multiple fields (including substructures).
I have another table (table2) which has 3 fields (all structures) and these 3 structures are the same as that of table1

Now  have to populate table2 from table 1 and i used the following query

`INSERT INTO table2
SELECT struct1, struct2, struct4 FROM table1`

But it is not populating the values in table2.
Any idea how can I achieve this?
Copying individual fields is a pain becuase their are nested structures present and struct 1 has got 85 fields, struct2 has 43 fields and struct5 has 78 fields.

Comment: can you post create table script for table1 and table2 and also sample data from table 1 and table 2

Comment: sorry, its a bank's customer sensitive data so can't share that

Comment: you don't have to share the actual data. Cook up some sample data  which follows the structure of  the actual data. Sample data helps users to understand your problems and solve it.